# How to make user function (group_by().apply and def function with agg functions)

Tags: python, pandas

friends!

I got this code:

```
def agr_list(x):
    f = {}
    f['quantity'] = sum(x['quantity'])
    f['revenue'] = sum(x['quantity']*x['price'])
    return pd.Series(f, index=['quantity', 'revenue'])
z6_g = (
    z6.
    groupby('name', as_index=False).
    apply(agr_list)
)
```

It's working, result is:

```
    name             quantity     revenue
0   Avocaddo         20           3556
1   Got meat!        2            818
2   Pineapple        2            620
3   Pineapple sort2  1            219
4   Dove             1            229
5   Cotico           1            149
6   Orange           6            1014
7   Peanut           7            315
8   Baguette         2            251
9   Kotanyi          1            59
```

Table to work with:

```
    name            quantity    price
0   Product_names   1           169
```

I just can't figure out how to make one custom function with this code.
Also I can't remake this code without def agr_list.

I can just get needed output with 2 custom functions:

```
def agr_list(x):
    f = {}
    f['quantity'] = sum(x['quantity'])
    f['revenue'] = sum(x['quantity']*x['price'])
    return pd.Series(f, index=['quantity', 'revenue'])
def gr(df, gr_col):
    return df.groupby(gr_col, as_index=False).apply(agr_list)
```

Expected output:

```
    name             quantity     revenue
0   Avocaddo         20           3556
1   Got meat!        2            818
2   Pineapple        2            620
3   Pineapple sort2  1            219
4   Dove             1            229
5   Cotico           1            149
6   Orange           6            1014
7   Peanut           7            315
8   Baguette         2            251
9   Kotanyi          1            59
```

P. S. I just found out how to make it. I just put my code here. Thx, if spend your time for this.

```
def gr(df, gr_col):

    def agr_list(x):
        f = {}
        f['quantity'] = sum(x['quantity'])
        f['revenue'] = sum(x['quantity']*x['price'])
        return pd.Series(f, index=['quantity', 'revenue'])

    return df.groupby(gr_col, as_index=False).apply(agr_list)
```

Comment: Sure, I've just edited question.

Comment: Look, first code in my post is working. I got rigth outpoot (group by name, sum for quantity and sum for quantity*price). I'm trying to make 1 function with this code or at least get needed output without def function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def gr(df, gr_col):

    def agr_list(x):
        f = {}
        f['quantity'] = sum(x['quantity'])
        f['revenue'] = sum(x['quantity']*x['price'])
        return pd.Series(f, index=['quantity', 'revenue'])

    return df.groupby(gr_col, as_index=False).apply(agr_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).